# e.target.classList not exists on onClick event in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

My issue is that `e.target` doesn't have the `classList` property when event handler for `click` is executing. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

interface props{
    imageUrl: string,
    setSelectdImage : (value: React.SetStateAction<string>) => void

}

const Modal:React.FC<props> = ({imageUrl,setSelectdImage}) => {
    return (
        <div className='fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-halfTransparent' onClick={ (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
            if(e.target.classList){  // here is issue
                setSelectdImage('')
            }
        }}>
            <img className="block max-w-4xl max-h-6 mt-24 mx-auto shadow-md" src={imageUrl} alt="large image"/>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging `e.target` and checked its value?

Answer (score 10):

from **Typescript 3.2.4** you can retrieve classList by this way:

`(e.target as Element).classList`